# ATM Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to fix this code where instead of withdrawing the money when the money buttons are pressed, I need it to be withdrawn when the withdraw button is clicked after the amount has been chosen.

Please help.  Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title> ATM Model 170-JavaScript Assignment 7: Valarie Salas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="$20" onclick='withdraw(20)'/></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Withdrawal" onclick='withdrawamount+'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="$60" onclick='withdraw(60)'/></td>
            <td>Current Balance</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Current Balance" value="5000.00" id="textField1" onchange=''/></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="$100" onclick='withdraw(100)'/></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="Other Amount" onclick='alert("Sorry.  This Function Is Not Available.")'/></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        alert("Please select the amount you would like to withdraw.")
        var balance=5000;

        function withdraw(amount)
        {
            var sure = confirm("Are you sure you want to withdraw $"+amount+" from this account?");
            if(sure == true)
            {
            balance = balance - amount;
            document.getElementById("textField1").value = balance;
            }else
            {
            alert("No withdrawal made");
            }
            alert("Your balance is "+balance);
        }



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Don't expect us to do your homework for you, without even trying yourself

Comment: I tried to figure out how to use a global variable but I just don't understand how they work and it fits into my program.  I thought I could set the variable to a button value but I can't.

Comment: fair enough, wait a bit... btw, your html is written wrong. I will update your question to fix that

Comment: And trust me I don't want you to do my homework.  I really do want to learn Javascript.  I'm only looking for some advice and pointers to steer me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

From your quote to *Dogoku*

> I really do want to learn Javascript. I'm only looking for some advice
>   and pointers to steer me in the right direction.

What i can suggest is, what about if you didn't use buttons for 20, 60 and 100, but instead made them to radio buttons, with Id.

So you can get the user to **select** how much they would like to withdraw, and **then click the withdraw button.** When they do, check to see which radio button is ***Checked***, and this can be done by **document.getElementById('nameOfYourRadioBtn')**.

This should help you get going. 
(Also remember to put a condition to make sure the user isnt able to select more than one radio button at any one time).

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction. Enjoy coding :)

Kush

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Kush!  If it wasn't a "must" to have buttons on my assignment, your suggestion would have been a great help.

Comment: You do indeed need to use a variable. If we said more we'd be helping you cheat. Kush's answer is a good suggestion. That they're button-looking doesn't mean they can't behave like radio buttons.

Comment: Defo agree with Chris, it just how strong javascript is,

Comment: But another alternative then would be, to create a javascript object, which has a property called "WithdrawalAmount", and assign this property the value every time the user clicks on a withdrawAmount button, then call the js object in you withdraw function, and the property you assigned, and use that value.

Comment: Kush that's a great alternative!  Thanks!  I'll try it and see what happens

Comment: My pc crashed, as I was writing a jsfiddle. I just managed to bring it back to life . It seems like you got the help you need